# observablemap in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am new to scala. I want to be notified whenever a map is modified. I thought this can be done using a observable map.

I am trying to define a object like below

```
var myObj = new Map[UUID, MyType] with ObservableMap[UUID,MyType]
```

but it does not compile saying..

```
error: object creation impossible, since:
method iterator in trait MapLike of type => Iterator[(java.util.UUID, MyType)] is not defined
method get in trait MapLike of type (key: java.util.UUID)Option[MyType] is not defined
method -= in trait ObservableMap of type (key: java.util.UUID)this.type is marked `abstract' and `override', but no concrete implementation could be found in a base class
method += in trait ObservableMap of type (kv: (java.util.UUID, MyType))this.type is marked `abstract' and `override', but no concrete implementation could be found in a base class
```

why is this so? How do you instantiate a ObservableMap?

Comment: OK..that was probably silly..I should have declared it as HashMap..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the methods in the trait ObseravableMap are abstract, which means you have to provide their implementations. Here is the [link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ObservableMap) to the API.

Your code should look something like this when your are done:

```
val myObj = new Map[UUID, MyType] with ObservableMap[UUID, MyType] {
   def get (key: A): Option[B] = // your implementation here
   def iterator : Iterator[(A, B)] = // your implementation here
}
```

Comment: but I thought get and iterator should be common to all maps..why should everyone provide their own implementation

Comment: This is correct, but you are instantiating a `Map`, which is a trait itself. If you want implementations of `get` and `iterator` to be provided for you, you need to instantiate a specific map, like for instance a `HashMap`.

Comment: ok you got there first..I have accepted your answer anyways..thx

Answer (score 6):

You need to mix `ObservableMap` in with a concrete map type.

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.collection.mutable._

scala> val map = new HashMap[Int, Int] with ObservableMap[Int, Int]
map: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int] with scala.collection.mutable.ObservableMap[Int,Int] = Map()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map` is an object that has an apply method which creates a new map instance, which is why you can do things like `val mymap = Map()`. But the map you're using is a trait, which has some abstract methods that you need to implement. Since both `Map` and `ObservableMap` have abstract elements, it doesn't work.

(I see that someone answered with what I was about to say, as I was typing- Garrett is right, you need to mix it in with a concrete type)

An alternative would be to create a `MapProxy` around the map you want to observe, and mix the `ObservableMap` with that.

Answer (score 0):

this is trait is meant to be used as a mixin. like:

```
val map = new HashMap[_,_] with ObservableMap[_,_]
```

however it's deprecated since scala_2.11.